# matlab - modulate

Tags: matlab

could somebody help me with this problem for Matlab:

I have a number 8 as a limit and want that I just get numbers in range from 1 to 8, how can I do it?
in MaxMsp this function is called "mod" so if I have mod8 than it will count until 8 and when 9 comes up it will output 1 again, 10 will be 2, 11 will be 3, 12 will be 4 etc.

this must be very simple but I just cannot find it in help.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to look in the help is by using the `lookfor` function, I guess typing `lookfor mod` (or `lookfor modulo`) in the command line should point you towards the `mod` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the [`mod()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html):

```
y = mod(x-1,8)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `M = mod(X,Y)` for example `M = mod(10,8)`

Answer (score 0):

using the `mod` function will give you numbers from `0-7`. So you need `mod+1`.

example: `out=mod(x,8)+1`